# Process variables from one method to another inside one class

Tags: python

Guys, I think how to process variables from one method into another inside one class. For example :

```
class Newclas:
    def getPortalSources(self,portal):
            self.connection_source=self.config.get("portal_"+portal,'Sources')
            self.portal=portal

    def getConnection(self,source):
            self.source=source
            self.connection_string=self.config.get('CONNECTION',self.portal+'_'+source+'_'+'connectstring')   ## Connection
```

Until now I used something like above. So on getConnection I used self.portal variable from getPortalSources method. However it is  still a little bit unclear for me.

Just wondering if there is some other better aproach to do something like that ? If so, could you give me some tips, or examples.

For example :

```
def getPortalSources(self,portal):
        self.connection_source=self.config.get("portal_"+portal,'Sources')
        self.portal=portal

def getConnection(source):
        self.connection_string=self.config.get('CONNECTION',getPortalSources.portal+'_'+source+'_'+'connectstring')   ## Connection
```

Of course it will not work, but I think then you got my idea.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is that you use constructor, or global variables.

I will give an example for constructor here:

```
class Newclas:
    def __init__(self,portal='default_portal',source='default_source'):
         self.portal = portal
         self.source = source

    def getPortalSources(self,portal=self.portal):
            self.connection_source=self.config.get("portal_"+portal,'Sources')


    def getConnection(self,source=self.source):
            self.connection_string=self.config.get('CONNECTION',self.portal+'_'+source+'_'+'connectstring')   ## Connection
```

So what's happening here is, when you create the object of this class you make like this:

```
new_obj = Newclas(portal='the_portal',source='the source')
```

using `portal='the_portal',source='the source'` is optional if you don't provide this they will take the default value.

And now when you say : `new_obj.getConnection()` it will provide you with that thing.

if you say : `new_obj.getConnection(source='some_other_source')` then it will give with that source.